# Open function with CSV file on Python

Tags: python, fopen, fwrite

Okay, what I want to do is to write something into a CSV file. I'm doing this:

```
directory = open('docs/directory.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8')
name = input('Please insert a name: ')
phone = input('Please insert a phone number: ')

directory.write(name + ',' + phone + ',\n')

print(directory.read())
```

I use `'a+'` to append every line at the end of the file. Here everything is okay, the data is being added to the end of the file everytime I run the script, but the problem is that the data is not being showed at the end, apparently, the `read()` function is not working.

Am I doing something wrong? Could you help me with this please? Thanks.

Comment: When you call `read()` what are you expecting to get?

Comment: The content of the file. That why I have directory.read()

Comment: That's not how it's going to work. See the answer from @mgilson for why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `read`, you read from the current position of the file pointer to the end of the file.  However, you have the file pointer at the end of the file already, so there is nothing returned.

In this case, I would open the file in `'rw+'` mode, seek to the end and then append stuff.

```
directory = open('docs/directory.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8')
directory.seek(0,2) #seek to the end

name = input('Please insert a name: ')
phone = input('Please insert a phone number: ')

directory.write(name + ',' + phone + ',\n')

directory.seek(0) #seek back to beginning
print(directory.read())
```

Comment: Well, thank's for your answer. I tried to use rw+, but I get an error, so I did something similar, I used a+ and the before print(directory.read()), I used directory.seek(0) and It worked. Thank's for your help.

Comment: @AndresOrozco -- sorry about that.  Updated and tested this time :)

Answer (score 0):

Python has a standard library for that called [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

resources:
["using csv module"](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
~$ cat test.py
name = raw_input('Please insert a name: ')
phone = raw_input('Please insert a phone number: ')

# Opening in a+ mode will point the file pointer to the end of the file.
# We will fix this with seek().
directory = open('test.csv', 'a+')

# Seek to the 0th offset from the end of the file (option 2).
directory.seek(0, 2)

# Write the data at the end of the file.
directory.write(name + ',' + phone + '\n')

# Seek to the beginning of the file (option 0).
directory.seek(0, 0)

# Read the file and print output.
print(directory.read())
```

```
~$ >test.csv
~$ python test.py
Please insert a name: Test Name 1
Please insert a phone number: 111-222-3344
Test Name 1,111-222-3344

~$ python test.py
Please insert a name: Test Name 2
Please insert a phone number: 222-333-4444
Test Name 1,111-222-3344
Test Name 2,222-333-4444

~$
```